# apt-get can not detect correct python version when using update-alternatives for python

Tags: apt, python, dpkg, aptitude, alternatives

I have installed different python versions on my Linux Mint DE. I used the `update-alternatives --set` statement to easily switch between the different versions.

Unfortunately sometimes `apt-get install` or `upgrade` or something similar have problems recognizing the correct python path. It seems to want to use python2.7, although I have set the correct alternative. I guess `apt-get` can't find out that `/usr/bin/python` points to `/etc/alternatives/python` and that to `/usr/bin/python2.7`.

If I manually create a symbolic link directly from `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python2.7` `apt-get` finishes without an error.

How can I use the alternatives option so that `apt-get` can correctly detect and use the configured python version?

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking this problem might have something to do with how the shell (Bash) hashes the paths to executables when they're called.

*excerpt from [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)*

> Bash uses a hash table to remember the full pathnames of executable
>   files (see hash under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).  A full search of
>   the directories in PATH is performed only if the command is not found
>   in the hash  table.

You can interrogate the hash using the `hash` command like so:

```
$ hash -l
builtin hash -p /usr/sbin/update-alternatives update-alternatives
builtin hash -p /usr/bin/man man
builtin hash -p /bin/ls ls
```

You can cause the hash to "forget" everything with the `-r` switch:

```
$ hash -r
manny@manny:~$ hash -l
hash: hash table empty
```

I would try running a `hash -r` prior to running `apt-get` to see if that resolves the issue.

Also I'd take a look at the output from `update-alternatives --query <command>` to make sure it contains the values you think it should. Here's mine for `java` just for an example:

```
$ update-alternatives --query java
Name: java
Link: /usr/bin/java
Slaves:
 java.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
Status: auto
Best: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Value: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

Alternative: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Priority: 1071
Slaves:
 java.1.gz /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
```